# Crossword code in PHP is not working in localhost

Tags: php

My problem is that crossword code in php is not working.

Author is able to run the code here is the link: http://phpcrossword.sourceforge.net/

And here is the code given by author https://github.com/laurynas/php-crossword

I download it but it is not working in my localhost. If anyone successfully run this code, please share how you got it working.

Comment: You've mentioned in a comment that you are getting an error. Please let us know what that error is, in your question please. Also, check to see when the last release of this software was - if it is very old then it won't have been tested against recent versions of PHP.

Comment: where we can get the documentation of php crossword? Any you have any idea ? @halfer

Comment: I've no idea - maybe there isn't any? Search the repos in the links you have provided, or try getting in touch with the author. If you are having trouble getting it to run, maybe it is for an old version of PHP, or maybe it is not very well written - these are common occurrences.

Comment: i can run it, that was due to old version and short tags.... i want to add somthing more

Comment: i also like to perform it differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, the errors occurs because of short code of php(`<?` change to `<?php`) you can turn it on from ini setting `short_open_tag=On` and the wrong index values in the code which generates notices turn of all errors, warnings by `error_reporting(0);` write this in your demo.php file and configure the database from sql folder. It will start working. Have a happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks You very much sir, I have short tag on. I keep error_reporting(0) at the top of the demo.php bt still not working. Error is comming

Comment: Try this one also to suppress the error http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php and accept answer if you like :)

Comment: if u have done before plz share it with me. its really making me problem

Comment: Yes I did, i did the same thing that i have added in my comment. 1) enable  the short tag. 2) suppress the errors 3) install the database and set the config of db to connfig file. let me know the error that you are facing so that i can give you the proper solution.

Comment: Undefined index: cols in C:\wamp\www\cross-master\init.php and there is $_REQUEST[cols] in coding. how to fix it

Comment: have you change all the short tags including config file.

Comment: yes i did all above like u did. I fix some problem like creating object $this->db =& new className() to $this->db = new className()

Comment: yes i change the short tags in every pages. didn't miss any one of them

Comment: now i am download a fresh coding and start doing bt no progress

Comment: How to fix Undefined index:cols of $_REQUEST[cols] in init.php

Comment: Download updated code from here http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=98900781709600772450

Comment: "; var_dump( $var ); print ""; } function getmicrotime(){ list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime()); return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec); } ?>

Comment: Change open tag `<?` into `<?php` at the top of **utility.php** file. It will solve your problem. You may find **utility.php** file from **lib** folder. Please comment below, if you find any error. @narayani

Comment: thanks u, last error was sort out by removing the meta tag in line 4.

Comment: demo-user-words.php i want to show the clue like in demo.php. how to do that? instead of textarea we can keep text field for 1 word and 1 text field for its clue. @Siva prakash and Ashish Ranade

Comment: where we can get the documentation of php crossword? Any body have any idea ?